# Determine the Value of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1+n)x^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, summation

For $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|x|<1$.  Find the value of

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1+n)x^n$$

Comment: Use integration (if you're allowed).

Comment: it should be solved without calculus use as the problem is from non calculus based curriculum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $$\sum_{n \geq 0 }(n+1)x^n =\sum_{n \geq 0 }nx^n + \sum_{n \geq 0 }x^n $$

And observe that$$ \sum_{n \geq 0 }nx^n =\sum_{n \geq 0 }x\frac{d}{dx}x^n= x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n \geq 0 }x^n$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I find it interesting that OP said above to not use calculus, and accepted your answer using a derivative.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1+n)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^n$$
$$\frac{1}{1-x}+x\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{1-x})=\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$