Exercise regarding formal power series

Consider the formal power series $a(z):=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)z^k$
and find it's inverse.

Approach:
I thought of rewriting $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)z^k$ to $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} kz^k + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k$.
Then by the well known "trick" of using the geometric series I get $\frac{1}{1-z}$ for $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k$.
For $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} kz^k$ I thought of writing it as $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k^{1/k}z)^k$ and using again the geometric series to get $\frac{1}{1-z}$ with the argument that for $k \rightarrow \infty$ the term $k^{1/k}$ converges to $1$. But this would imply $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)z^k=\frac{2}{1-z}=2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k$, which seems wrong.
I found the following post which uses differentiation, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1322794.
I am interested if there is some other way to solve this, i.e. without calculus.

You can't apply the geometric series with a "common ratio" $k^{\frac1k}z$ because the ratio varies, so that's where your idea goes astray.

Hint: look at $a(z)-za(z)$.

The inverse will be a power series $b(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x_kz^k$ such that$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)z^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty x_kz^k\right)=1.$$In other words:

$x_0=1$;
$2x_0+x_1=0(\iff x_1=-2)$;
$3x_0+2x_1+x_2=0(\iff x_2=1)$;
$4x_0+3x_1+2x_2+x_3=0(\iff x_3=0)$

and so on. In fact, $x_n=0$ for each $n>2$, because if $x_0=1$, $x_1=-2$, $x_2=1$ and $x_k=0$ if $k\in\{3,4,\ldots,n-1\}$, then, since$$nx_0+(n-1)x_1+(n-2)x_2+\cdots+2x_{n-1}+x_n=0$$and, on the other hand,$$nx_0+(n-1)x_1+(n-2)x_2+\cdots+2x_{n-1}=n-2(n-1)+n-2=0$$you have $x_n=0$.

Deus Ex Machina:
let $g(z) = \frac{1}{1-z} = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4...$  and compute the first few terms for $g^2(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$
$$  1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + z^5 + \cdots$$
$$  +\hspace{12mm} z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + z^5 + z^6 + \cdots$$
$$  +\hspace{20mm}  z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + z^5 + z^6 + z^7 + \cdots$$
$$  +\hspace{30mm}   z^3 + z^4 + z^5 + z^6 + z^7 + z^8 + \cdots$$
$$  +\hspace{40mm}    z^4 + z^5 + z^6 + z^7 + z^8 + z^9 + \cdots$$
so that
$$  g^2(z) = 1 + 2 z + 3 z^2 + 4 z^3 + 5 z^4  ...$$
which is precisely your series
You wanted an "inverse,"  in case that means inverse function, take $  x = \frac{1}{(1-y)^2},$  next $(1-y)^2 = \frac{1}{x},$ so that $|1-y| =  \frac{1}{ \sqrt x}.$  Either $y = 1 +  \frac{1}{ \sqrt x}$  or  $y = 1 -  \frac{1}{ \sqrt x}$  and it is the second one that fits with the original $z < 1$
